# cucumber test in rails application does not seem to be submitting a form to log a user in

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, webrat

I am trying to test my rails app using cucumber and webrat. I'm trying to get the test to login as a user who is already created and stored in the database, and I'm getting the following error:

Then I see a login error message        # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:16
      expected the following element's content to include "Welcome admin":

```
    Csa
        Welcome Guest
        Forgot password?
        or
        Register
      HomeJobs
        English
  Cymraeg
    Welcome to CS-Alumni News
  The is where the home page text will go.
   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:18:in `/^I see a login error message$/'
  features/users/login.feature:9:in `Then I see a login error message'
```

I changed the code to get it to login a user instead of failing to log in a user due to invalid details, as that wasn't working, and I wasn't sure if it was because it didn't pick up the flash message or not.

Here is the step_definitions file (user_steps.rb)

```
require 'webrat'

Given /^I do not have an account$/ do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    @user ||= User.where(:email >= @user[:email]).first
    @user.destroy unless @user.nil?
end

When /^I attempt to login with my details$/ do
    visit new_session_path
    fill_in "login-input", :with => "admin" 
    fill_in "password", :with => "taliesin" 
    clicks_button "Login"
end 

Then /^I see a login error message$/ do 
    visit home_path
    response.should contain("Welcome admin")
end

And /^I should not be logged in$/ do
    #response.should_not contain("Welcome admin")
end
```

Here is the login.feature file:

```
Feature: Login
    In order to access my account 
    As a user
    I want to be able to login 

        Scenario: User does not have an account
            Given I do not have an account
            When I attempt to login with my details 
            Then I see a login error message
            And I should not be logged in

        Scenario: User enters incorrect Login
            Given I have an account
            And I am not logged in
            When I enter an incorrect Login
            Then I see a login error message
            And I should not be logged in

        Scenario: User enters incorrect password
            Given I have an account
            And I am not logged in
            When I enter an incorrect password
            Then I see a login error message
            And I should not be logged in

        Scenario: User logs in successfully
            Given I have an account
            And I am not logged in
            When I enter my correct login
            And I enter my correct password
            Then I see a successful login message
            When I return to the application 
            Then I should still be logged in
```

Here is the env.rb file;

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'webrat'
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'

Webrat.configure do |config|
config.mode = :rack
config.open_error_files = false
end

World(Webrat::Methods)
World(Webrat::Matchers)

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false


begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish              to use it."
  end

 Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
setup do |session|
session.host! "localhost:3001"
end
end

rails/blob/master/features/choose_javascript_database_strategy.feature
Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

Here is the gemfile:

```
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.3.0"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '4.1.2'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:    https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
  end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem "webrat"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'selenium-client'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so your step is this:

```
Then /^I see a login error message$/ do 
   visit home_path
   response.should contain("Welcome admin")
end
```

And the error you're getting is: `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError`

I think it's just a case of you're expectation is wrong, but is at least a bit misleading. We should actually see an error (something like "Cannot login") but we are looking for `"Welcome admin"` which seems more like a welcome message.

We can debug this by placing `puts response.body` before the expectation to see what is being rendered.

It may also be that the cucumber isn't waiting for the request to finish. We could try adding `find('#some-element')` which will wait for a few seconds before failing if it cannot find an element.

Edit: Also, I just noticed the feature that you were running isn't the one you included (`login.feature`) so you're trying to see an error message without attempting an incorrect login.

Comment: Thank you, it's sorted now.